# Visual Studio Nov 2013 CTP non-capturing lambda unary operator+() decay

Tags: c++, lambda

I would like to decay a non-capturing lambda expression to a function pointer using the unary operator+() trick. In MSVC Nov 2013 CTP, the template specialization is ambiguous because the clever Microsoft chaps want to make it possible to also specify the calling convention of the function.
Is there some way of uniquifying operator+()?

Comment: Any particular reason to not use `static_cast`?

Comment: Non-capturing, non-auto (C++14/msvc2015).  Your code becomes less and less useful in the future...

Comment: You *could* deduce the signature from `operator()`, but I'm not sure if that's a good idea: http://rextester.com/QXC14410

Comment: @Shafik: The static cast has to come before unary operator+(). What incantation works with VC++?

Comment: See this example [here]( http://rextester.com/EITZL29705) ... if that does not help then you need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Shafik: The static cast has to come before unary operator+(), I think. What incantation works with VC++? Everything works fine with gcc 5.1.0. It seems to be a Microsoft specific calling convention issue. 
@rextester: Do you mean from `operator()` on the anonymous lambda? How?
I've been using local types as a workaround to actually capture parameters.. See, e.g., https://github.com/keithalewis/fms/blob/master/poly/horner.h
@Yakk: I'm trying to write useful code now.

Comment: Thanks for the super fast response. I was editing my post when I exceeded the 5min SO edit time limit. Funny. I gave a 5 minute talk at Bloomberg tonight. It went over like a lead balloon: http://kalx.net/njr.html. The only relationship to my question is that I am trying to reimplement my old code in modern C++.
The example I gave is not at all minimal, complete, and verifiable.
Looking at your rextester code now. What an amazing world we live in. It will take me more than 5 minutes to figure out how to illustrate the issue with MSVC specific function call conventions.

Comment: `int main () { auto f = +[](int i) { return i; }; }` should produce the 'operator+ is ambiguous' error messages. I'd like to disambiguate those..